# SSL/TLS on linux mint using XAMPP?

Tags: linux-mint, ssl, https, xampp

I have a basic website that I want to get HTTPS on. It's like the crowning jewel to me. However, I am using linux mint for the server. All the tutorials I can find for it are on windows, using a certificate generator. I couldn't find a certificate generator in the /opt/lampp/ folder. could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). This site/service offer free certificates for everyone.

[Here](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache) you can find instructions how to install and manage the things. They are for Ubuntu, but AFAIK Mint is Ubuntu based.